# on scaling canvas, toDataURL only returns visible part of canvas, not the part out of canvas size

Tags: javascript, angular, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to freehand draw on image within canvas, along with zoom in/out.

to add drawing change on image I am using ***getImageData()*** & ***putImageData()*** and then saving the image using 
***canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL();***

it works fine without zoom, but when i zoom in using ***context.scale(x,x);***
***canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL();*** saves only image that is visible in canvas area, and the image part that went out of canvas size after zooming was lost.

I want to get complete image with drawing changes, when zoomed out, is there any alternative for ***toDataURL()*** which can give me complete image data.

Comment: I've not done anything like this before but would a work around be to reset the zoom when you save it, do the save, then put the zoom back to what it was prior to save?

Comment: You may paint your image on the screen canvas and also on a buffer canvas (not attached to the DOM) The buffer canvas may be as big as the scaled image, and you can use   ` toDataURL()` on the buffer canvas.

Comment: @enxaneta I tried your approach, it worked. you can add your comment as answer, I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may paint your image on the screen canvas and also on a buffer canvas (not attached to the DOM) The buffer canvas may be as big as the scaled image, and you can use `toDataURL()` on the buffer canvas